# Shared preference value returns empty

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

i am fetching value from server and saving to shared preference and retrieving it into string but the value is empty can any one say me whats gone wrong.and any suggestions how to compare the values in channel and link strings.
[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L11VW.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
EditText name;
EditText email;
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://telview360/";
private static String URL = "http://54.179.134.139/viView360Service/WebService.asmx?WSDL";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://telview360/ImageDetails";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "ImageDetails";
String link;
String channel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                link = response.toString();

                Log.d("Web response", ":" + link);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    networkThread.start();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Name, link);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d("Saved value",":"+editor.commit());



    channel = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "");
    Log.d(" value",":"+channel);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: check your `link` value which is empty or is there any value?

Comment: u can see in web response in logcat  there is a value coming from server

Comment: write Your Sharedpreference inside your thread after the line
                link = response.toString();

Comment: editor.commit(); will work but for better performance use editor.apply();

Comment: thanks  @ Mohammad nabil it reutns value now and i need one more suggestion if the link value is changed i need to replace the value in channel with new value of link how to compare them

Comment: get the value String value = sharedPrefrence.getString(key, ""); if(!value.equal(newResponse)){ //will update your previous value on same key SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Name, link);
    editor.apply();}

Comment: no Mohammad nabi i need to compare previously saved value  and fresh value from link

Comment: yes bro! that is the logic for your query, pls try and check whether its full fill your query or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
EditText name;
EditText email;
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://telview360/";
private static String URL = "http://54.179.134.139/viView360Service/WebService.asmx?WSDL";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://telview360/ImageDetails";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "ImageDetails";
String link;
String channel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                link = response.toString();

sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Name, link);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d("Saved value",":"+editor.commit());



    channel = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "");
    Log.d(" value",":"+channel);

                Log.d("Web response", ":" + link);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    networkThread.start();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i can get value now and one more suggestion if the link value is changed by comparing with stored value in channel and update it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code after `editor.commit();` :-

```
editor.apply();
```

Comment: This will save instantly and use it after that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    EditText name;
    EditText email;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://telview360/";
    private static String URL = "http://54.179.134.139/viView360Service/WebService.asmx?WSDL";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://telview360/ImageDetails";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "ImageDetails";
    String link;
    String channel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                    link = response.toString();
                    UpdateLinkValue(link);
                    Log.d("Web response", ":" + link);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        networkThread.start();
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    channel = getPrefLink(MainActivity.this);
    Log.d(" value",":"+channel);
    }

    public void UpdateLinkValue(String link){
          String prevLink = getPrefLink(MainActivity.this);
          if(!prevLink.lenght() > 0 || !prevLink.equals(link))
              setPrefLink(MainActivity.this,link);
    }
    public void setPrefLink(Context context, String link) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferencesEditor(context);
            editor.putString(mypreference , link);        
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
        }

public SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public String getPrefLink(Context context) {          
            return getPreferences(context).getString(mypreference , "");
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

If you make functions to save preference & to get It, you can call them from any where.

Comment: getPreferencesEditor(context) cannot be resolved it says

Comment: and more ever now i can get value and one more suggestion if the link value is changed by comparing with stored value in channel and update it